# How can I average daily data into weekly data while still separating by a factor?

Tags: r

I am surprisingly having trouble using the search function on stackoverflow to find a solution to this that works with my dataset. This is the head of my data:

```
 head(data2)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Date       Treatment response_source response
  <date>     <fct>     <chr>              <dbl>
1 2018-05-01 100%      Precipitation       1.47
2 2018-05-01 100%      Irrigation          0   
3 2018-05-01 100%      ET                  0   
4 2018-05-01 100%      Leaching           -1.47
5 2018-05-02 100%      Precipitation       0   
6 2018-05-02 100%      Irrigation          0
```

This goes on for a few more months. I am using the following code to make a ggplot:

```
ggplot(data2, aes(fill= response_source, y=response, x=Date)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~Treatment, nrow=4)
```

Overall it works well (although for some reason it isn't plotting values larger than 1.0 or -1.0), but I would like to report the data as a weekly total instead of daily. I would still like a separate bar for each response_source, but I do not know how to sum the daily values together into weekly while keeping the sources separate.

My only thought is to maybe use something like  `pivot_wider` to create a wide dataset, make my weekly sums, and then use  `pivot_longer`  to convert it back into long data, but this feels sloppy.

What is the best way to go about doing this? Any help would be hugely appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good application for `lubridate::week()`.

**Example Data**

```
> data2 <- data.frame(Date = c("2018-05-01", "2018-07-02"), response_source = c("Precipitation", "Irrigation"), response = c(1.47, 0))
> data2
        Date response_source response
1 2018-05-01   Precipitation     1.47
2 2018-07-02      Irrigation     0.00
```

**Code**

```
data2 %>%  
       mutate(week = lubridate::week(Date)) %>% 
                   group_by(response_source, week) %>% 
                               summarise(Summe = sum(response))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   response_source [2]
  response_source  week Summe
  <chr>           <dbl> <dbl>
1 Irrigation         27  0   
2 Precipitation      18  1.47
```

---

**Extra**

If you want to recover the start of the week from the week number, you can do

```
data2 %>% 
     mutate(ExactDate = lubridate::ymd("2018-01-01") + lubridate::weeks(week - 1))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   response_source [2]
  response_source  week Summe ExactDate 
  <chr>           <dbl> <dbl> <date>    
1 Irrigation         27  0    2018-07-02
2 Precipitation      18  1.47 2018-04-30
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had seen lubridate before, but wasn't familiar with it. This was an excellent way to solve the issue, and I appreciate the addition for the start of the week's date as well.